# Mysql alike date functions in Morphia

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, function, date

I am in progress of migration a JPA/MySQL application to mongodb using morphia. I have some queries like

```
AND DATE(NOW()) > (DATE(created) + 2)
```

or

```
AND ( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,kickoff,now()) > 1 )
```

or

```
AND DATE(ending) = DATE(NOW())
```

Is there anything similar in morphia or mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I understand that you ask for a way to create date queries in *MongoDB* and how would your write that query in *Morphia*

The Cookbook for date queries can be found [here](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/).

As pointed in the above post, you should use a range query for this.

In MongoDB's shell, for your first query, you would write it like this:

```
// hope I got the date part right XD
db.posts.find({created: {$lt: new Date().getDate() - 2}});
```

For range queries morphia has 2 ways:

- using the filter method
- using directly the [comparator methods](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#methods).

So the first query would become something like this:

```
myObjDao.createQuery().field("created").lessThan(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 2 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 )).fetch();
```